# Click area outside button area with Swift 3 Info Dark button type

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode8

My problem is that when using the Info Dark button type with Swift 3 Xcode 8.3 it is for some reason placed inside two ImageViews. I.e. UIButton/ImageView/ImageView. The first ImageView's area is bigger than that of the second ImageView (which contains the info image).

See image:

[image: extra image view with bigger area with Info Dark button type]

With a System button type this is not the case.

See image:

[image: not extra image view with System button type]

Will be appreciated if someone can help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button's clip to bounds to true.

[clip to bounds checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzvmW.png)

Comment: Ah thats strange that doesn't work, that should clip the unbutton's subviews and seems to have done that job when I tested it. Sorry can't help you more on this one ;/